# Summations of Products of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

It seems that the following equation is true for any $k<N$ (after verifying a lot of $k$ and $N$):

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=k}^{N} (-1)^j
\begin{pmatrix}
N\\j
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
j\\k
\end{pmatrix}
= 0
\end{equation}

But I want to proof it, any ideas?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: call this number $a_k$ and compute the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k x^k$.

Comment: I try, but the j is start from k, not 0

Comment: Use the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) $[k\le j]$ and swap the summations.